# Could EclipseLink be causing a ORA-00957: duplicate column name error because of a @DiscriminatorColumn in a polymorphic entity?

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, jakarta-ee, eclipselink

I'm getting this exception in an attempt to persist an **entity** object in an Oracle database, and I only started getting this error after switching my JPA project to **EclipseLink 2.0** from **Hibernate**, and I'm using "entity **inheritance**" if this could have anything to do with it (which I highly suspect).

*

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00957: duplicate column name
Error Code: 957
Call: INSERT INTO SUREC (ID, PERSON_ID, SURECID, VERSIYONNO, FAZ, FORM_TARIH, DURUMKODU_ID, surecId) VALUES (...
```

*

The exception message suggests that SURECID is generated twice in the SQL which seems to be causing the *duplicate column* error, however surecId is defined once as a property and annotated as a discriminator column in the entity class: (see below)

The base entity class resembles:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "surecId")
public class Surec implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6008473677883005878L;
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "FAZ")
    private int faz;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "FORM_TARIH")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date formTarih;
    @Column(name = "PERSON_ID")
    private Integer personId;
    // @Column(name = "SURECID", updatable = false, length=17)
    @Column(updatable = false, length=17)
    private String surecId;
    @Column(name = "VERSIYONNO")
    private Long versiyonno;
    @JoinColumn(name = "DURUMKODU_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    @ManyToOne
    private DurumKod durumKodu;

    public Surec() {
    }

    public Surec(String surecId) {
        this.surecId = surecId;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    .
    .
    .
    public String getSurecId() {
        return surecId;
    }

    public void setSurecId(String surecId) {
        this.surecId = surecId;
    }
    .
    .
    .
```

I commented the "@Column(name=..." annotation jus to see if it could be causing the duplicate column error, but it didn't work out.

And below is the polymorphic entity extending *Surec.java* above:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("atf")
public class MailOrder extends Surec {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8333637555543614502L;

    @Column(name = "AMOUNT")
    private Double amount;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "CURRENCY", length = 17)
    private String currency;
    @Column(name = "BANK")
    private String Bank;
    @Column(name = "ACCOUNT_ID", length = 31)
    private String accountId;
    @Column(name = "INVOICE_ID")
    private Integer invoiceId;

    public MailOrder() {
    }

    public MailOrder(String surecId) {
        super(surecId);
    }

    public String getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }
    .
    .
    .
```

The error occurs when I try to persist this very sub-entity.
It doesn't override any property of its superclass, although I'm not sure if it's the constructor...

Any advise to resolve the problem (and acknowledgement of any possible EclipseLink or Oracle (or my!) bug will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common issue if you have a relationship mapping that uses this field, and has to do with case sensitivity.  Try indicating the descriminator colum as 
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "SURECID")

EclipseLink is case sensitive by default, which is why surecId is seen as a different field from SURECID.  You can make EclipseLink case insensitive by using the eclipselink.jpa.uppercase-column-names property, which when set to true, forces EclipseLink to use the upper case on field name comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to mark the property as `insertable = false, updateable = false`, since it's already inserted as a discriminator:

```
@Column(insertable = false, updatable = false, length=17)
private String surecId;
```

Comment: logically you're right since a discriminator column should be defined as @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false, however in my case (prior to switching to EclipseLink from Hibernate) the surecId fields in the database table were blank in all rows (is this normal?) so I felt forced to create all objects extending Surec by doing the following:                         Surec mailorder = new Surec(); mailorder.setSurecId("atf"); as setting the surecId at creation time by a constructor using discrim. column argument was not foolproof in some cases  (e.g. Surec s = new Surec("atf");